# http.ListenAndServe handler function executed twice on port 80

Tags: go

If I run the following simple http server code on port 8080 everything works as expected. If I run the same code on port 80, by just changing the port, the handler function is executed twice with each request. Why, and how to fix it?

```
// httptest project main.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "html"
)

var count int

func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    count++
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q count=%d", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path), count)
    fmt.Println(count,r.RemoteAddr)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", defaultHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

If I enter localhost:8080 in the browser, I get a response with a count starting at 1 and increased by 1 with each new request.

If I change the code to port 80 and enter just localhost or localhost:80 in the browser, I get a first response with a count starting at 1 but increased by two with each following request. At the same time the print statement for the console output is executed twice.

Terminal console when running on port 80 with 3 requests:

```
>go run main.go
1 [::1]:51335
2 [::1]:51335
3 [::1]:51335
4 [::1]:51335
5 [::1]:51335
6 [::1]:51335
```

The responses in the browser are `Hello, "/" count=1`, `Hello, "/" count=3` and `Hello, "/" count=5`.

I've been running this locally on Windows 10 with Go version go1.9.2 windows/amd64 and the latest Google Chrome Browser.

However, I detected the issue in a simple web application on a remote Linux server where the code has been compiled with go version go1.9.1 linux/amd64.

Comment: Fix by adding `if r.URL.Path != "/" { http.Error(w, "Not Found", 404); return }` to beginning of handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just tried it on my pc with Fiddler open

I noticed when navigating to the url using Google Chrome, the browser makes 2 request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
```

the request for the favicon also gets handled by the defaultHandler, which causes the count to increment

I also tried with firefox and it doesn't send another request for the favicon

Answer (score 2):

Try to log requests. Possibly browser is calling `/favicon.ico`